# How to get GNU-Screen Command in Linux to echo locally

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, echo

I'm looking to run screen

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 115200
```

and echo my commands locally. This is one of those rare phrases where google spits out a lot of irrelevant results.

Comment: I believe that some people might face a situation where manually enabling local echo via e.g. `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 echo` works correctly. But then, when GNU Screen is started, it overwrites this mode and disables echo again. So the question is how to force GNU Screen to keep local echo enabled on a serial port which has it disabled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I had an open screen session and didn't know how to reconnect to it, so I forced a new session by `sudo screen` and that session was extremely messed up (corrupt characters) and didn't echo 90% of the characters. I was able to reconnect to that session and all was well.

Comment: You have asked a relevant question. But this remark does not answer it.